# Killing Python webservers

Tags: python

I am looking for a simple Python webserver that is easy to kill from within code. Right now, I'm playing with Bottle, but I can't find any way at all to kill it in code. If you know how to kill Bottle (in code, no Ctrl+C) that would be super, but I'll take anything that's Python, simple, and killable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use this.

```
import os
os._exit(3)
```

To crash in a 'controlled' way.

Comment: @Daniel Straight: We called it "controlled if you don't mind the consequences".   We use it mostly for automated testing where incomplete log entries or trashed databases don't matter.

Comment: Fortunately, I'm doing neither logging nor databasing (nor disk I/O), so this should be good.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to kill a process from Python, on a Unix-like platform, you can send signals equivalent to Ctrl-C at the console using Pythons os module e.g.

```
# Get this processes PID
pid_of_process = os.getpid()
# Send the interrupt signal to this process
os.kill(pid_of_process, signal.SIGINT)
```

Answer (score 1):

Raise exeption and handle it in main or use sys.exit

Comment: Both of these seem to be swallowed by Bottle.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting

```
import sys
```

at the top and the command

```
sys.exit(0)
```

In the code that handles the "kill request".